# Why doesn't the List fuse as well as the Vector? (Haskell)

Tags: performance, haskell, fusion

Consider the following benchmark:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Criterion.Main



goodSum :: Int -> Double
{-# NOINLINE goodSum #-}
goodSum n =
  let ints = U.enumFromN 0 (n * n * 10) :: U.Vector Int
  in U.foldl' (+) 0 $ U.map fromIntegral ints

badSum :: Int -> Double
{-# NOINLINE badSum #-}
badSum n = L.foldl' (+) 0.5 [fromIntegral i | i <- [0 .. 10*n*n]]

badSum2 :: Int -> Double
{-# NOINLINE badSum2 #-}
badSum2 n = L.foldr (+) 0.5 [fromIntegral i | i <- [0 .. 10*n*n]]

worstSum :: Int -> Double
{-# NOINLINE worstSum #-}
worstSum n = L.foldl1' (+) $ do
  i <- [0 .. n*n]
  return $ L.foldl1' (+) $ do
    k <- [0 .. 10]
    return $ fromIntegral $ k + i

main = do
  defaultMain
    [ bench "good" $ nf goodSum 500
    , bench "bad" $ nf badSum 500
    , bench "bad2" $ nf badSum2 500
    , bench "worst" $ nf worstSum 500
    ]
```

The results:

```
benchmarking good
time                 1.826 ms   (1.819 ms .. 1.835 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.810 ms   (1.803 ms .. 1.817 ms)
std dev              23.18 μs   (19.91 μs .. 27.96 μs)

benchmarking bad
time                 38.38 ms   (38.07 ms .. 38.74 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 38.23 ms   (38.07 ms .. 38.38 ms)
std dev              298.5 μs   (220.6 μs .. 417.8 μs)

benchmarking bad2
time                 77.87 ms   (73.74 ms .. 82.67 ms)
                     0.992 R²   (0.976 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 78.14 ms   (75.33 ms .. 82.13 ms)
std dev              5.184 ms   (3.056 ms .. 7.966 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking worst
time                 80.80 ms   (79.53 ms .. 82.10 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 80.73 ms   (80.29 ms .. 81.19 ms)
std dev              756.9 μs   (591.9 μs .. 938.2 μs)
```

List comprehensions are [good producers and `foldr` is a good consumer](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html), so why didn't the List fuse?

Comment: fyi - `Double` has an `Enum` instance, so the `map` is unnecessary - `(\n -> enumFromTo 0 $ fromIntegral n) :: Int -> [Double]`

Comment: rampion: thanks, but I wanted to be sure it was doing the conversion from Int to Double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to your question, `foldr` and the list comprehension did, in fact,
fuse. However, you have to recall the definition of `foldr` and not that it is
not a tail recursive function. The prelude defines `foldr` as, which will not
compile down to a tight loop like the `Vector` based example.

```
foldr k z = go
  where
    go []     = z
    go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

The important bit of core generated for `badSum2` looks like this

```
$wgo_s8AH [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Int# -> Double#
$wgo_s8AH =
  \ (w_s8AD :: Int#) ->
    case tagToEnum#
           @ Bool (==# w_s8AD y1_a69V)
    of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      False ->
        case $wgo_s8AH (+# w_s8AD 1) of ww_s8AG { __DEFAULT ->
        +## (int2Double# w_s8AD) ww_s8AG
        };
      True -> +## (int2Double# w_s8AD) 0.5
```

which is roughly equivalent to this function (modulo unboxed arithmetic)

```
badSum3 :: Int -> Double
badSum3 n = go 0
  where
    stop = 10 * n * n

    go i | i == stop = fromIntegral i + 0.5
         | otherwise = fromIntegral i + go (i + 1)
```

Running this through Criterion, this function gives the same runtime as
`badSum2`. While the generated function is not producing and consuming intermediate cons cells, it is still performing function calls and doing all the associated stack operations.

The poor performance for for the `foldl'` based version is due to the fact that `foldl'` is not a good consumer, so it cannot fuse with the list comprehension. The left-fold will produce a tail recursive loop which walks the list produced by the list comprehension, incurring the overhead of all the allocation and associated memory operations.

I am not sure if you can get the same performance as the `Vector` operations using the standard list operations, but the [stream-fusion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/docs/Data-List-Stream.html) package provides list combinators using a different fusion method, which can achieve similar performance for this problem.

```
import qualified Data.List.Stream as S

-- The stream-fusion package does not seem to have `enumFrom` functions
enumerate :: Int -> [Int]
enumerate n = S.unfoldr f 0
  where
    f i | i > n     = Nothing
        | otherwise = Just (i, i + 1)

goodSum2 :: Int -> Double
goodSum2 n = S.foldl' (+) 0.5 $ S.map fromIntegral $ enumerate (n * n * 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `foldl'` is still 15x worse than the Vector version.

Comment: @yong That is because `foldl'` will not fuse with the producer at all, so you still have the overhead of allocating cons cells to convey data from the producer to the consumer.